# Rails: RESTful Find, Initialize, or Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rest

I have an app that has Cities in it. I'm looking for some suggestions on how to RESTfully structure a controller so that I can lookup, initialize, and create city records via AJAX requests. For instance:

- Given a text field `city_name`
- A user enters the name of a City, like "Paris, France"
- The app checks this location to see if there is such a city in the database already
- If there is, it returns the city object
- If there is not, it returns a new record initialized with the name "Paris" and the country "France", and prompts the user to confirm they want to add this city to the database
- If the user says "Yes" the record is saved. If not the record is discarded and the form is cleared.

Now, my first approach was to change the Create action to use `find_or_create`, so that an AJAX post to `cities_path` would result in either returning the existing city or creating it and returning it.

That works ok... However, it would be better to setup controller actions that would take a string input, find , or else initialize and return, then only create if the user confirms the generated record is correct. The ideal scenario would put this all in one action so AJAX request can go to that url, the server responds with JSON objects, and javascript can handle things from there. I'd like to keep all the user-interaction logic client side, and also minimize the number of requests it takes to achieve this.

Any suggestions on the cleanest, most RESTful way to accomplish this?

Comment: To be clear: I'm aware of the existence of `find_or_initialize_by_`, what I'm looking for suggestions on is what controller actions to use for what behavior to keep this as clean and restful as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to take advantage of the exists? method:

```
if City.exists?(:name=>params[:city])
  @city = City.find_by_name(params[:city])
else
  @city = City.new(:name=>params[:city])
end
```

Update based on comment:

```
#show = /city/:id, :id can be int or string

def show
  if params[:id].to_i > 0
    @city = City.find(params[:id])
  elsif City.exists?(:name=>params[:id])
    @city = City.find_by_name(params[:id])
  else
    return redirect_to(:action=>:new, :name=>params[:id])
  end
end

def new
  @city = City.new(params[:name])
end
```

Comment: Sure, but is this in the `create` or `show` action? Do you use one action for find or initialize and another for create, or do you get all the behavior into one action, or.... that's really what I'm getting at. Thanks for the observation!

Comment: You could use the logic in either.  The code i provided would just get you the instance or initialize a new instance.

Comment: If you are asking which action would I call with ajax, i would likely use the show and redirect to create if it didn't exist

Comment: Yeah, what I'm looking for is an example of how you would setup the controller, I'm pretty familiar with the `find_or_initialize` and `find_or_create` methods.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.